# preload html5 audio in order

Tags: jquery, html5-audio

I have a list of songs I want to play when the user clicks a button, but it seems that the songs all try to load at the same time so it takes a while for it to load.  If I leave the page open for about 5 minutes the music will finally play, but I would like it to not have to wait 5 min.
So is there a way to force Song1 to fully load by itself, then have Song2 load by itself, etc.

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = $(".audio-player").length;
    var z = 0;

    $("#play").click(function(){
        $(".audio-player")[z].play();
    });
    $("#pause").click(function(){
        $(".audio-player")[z].pause();
    });
    $("#skip").click(function(){
        $(".audio-player")[z].pause();
        z++;
        if (z >= x) z = 0;
        $(".audio-player")[z].play();
        $(".audio-player")[z].currentTime = 0;
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<p id="play">Play</p>
<p id="pause">Pause</p>
<p id="skip">Next</p>

<audio class="audio-player" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64455636/tumblr/music/1/Apollo.mp3"></audio>
<audio class="audio-player" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64455636/tumblr/music/1/Daydreamer.mp3"></audio>
<audio class="audio-player" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64455636/tumblr/music/1/Delayed%20Friend%20Request.mp3"></audio>
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaketr00/g8vduvaf/)

Comment: There's always the preload attribute: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_preload.asp I'm not sure how you could get the browser to only preload one file at at time though.

Comment: @ReLeaf i tried using the preload tags but they dont work like I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need 1 audio tag, instead of 3. You can also load the audio dynamically from an array when the user presses play - so you don't need to load any audio when the page loads.

I have updated your fiddle here to show you it working: http://jsfiddle.net/g8vduvaf/6/

You can load the audio dynamically, like this:

```
var audioFiles = ["url","url2","url3"];

var z = 0;
var audioPlayer = $("#audioPlayer")[0];

var playAudio = function(){
   audioPlayer.src = audioFiles[z];
   audioPlayer.load();
   audioPlayer.play();    
}
```

Comment: I just found out that for some reason my connection with Dropbox is bad (trying to fix my connection right now), so I can't test your method right now

Comment: I had to go to Internet Explorer to get Dropbox to work (issue with google chrome? possibly cookies), and it works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @Jaketr00 Glad to be of help!